# OkHttp - Adding attributes to body

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

Does anyone have experience with the OkHttp websocket library? I'm creating a simple chatroom app and my current issue is when my android client connects to the websocket server, it only gives the client's connection id. I'm trying add attributes to the body of the request, but I can't seem to get it working with OkHttp.

````
RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
.add("room_id", "e9502c54-927c-4639-a94f-8d03149c9c62")
.build();```


Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.com")
                .method("POST", requestBody)
                .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.com")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
````

I'm trying to add a room_id so when the user is successfully connected, it logs the connectionid+roomid to manage the chat rooms however I can't figure out how to add attributes to the body

---

**Edit 1:**

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.come")
                .build();

        EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

This works when establishing the connection for the first time, but I can't seem to figure out how to add body attributes to this.

Comment: Why not send a message through the socket after the connection is successful?@Override public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    webSocket.send("Room_Id");
  }

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks for responding, it's because I am using two seperate AWS Lambda functions, one for sending messages and one for connecting. So when it connects, I want to get the connectionId and roomId using only that function, so I don't have to make another call to my sending message function.

Comment: I can't figure out how to add body attributes when connecting to websocket server for first time